# myorigin not being set for postfix

Tags: postfix

I am running a website on two AWS EC2 instances running Ubuntu 16.04.4 LTS.

I edit /etc/postfix/main.cf and uncomment

```
myorigin = /etc/mailname
```

I then enter

```
 sudo postfix reload
  echo $myorigin
```

and get nothing (blank)

I then enter

```
  sudo service postfix restart
  echo $myorigin
```

and get nothing (blank).  I do not understand why myorigin is not being set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're setting `myorigin` in a Postfix configuration file.

`echo $myorigin` will display the contents of a shell or environment variable named `myorigin`, which has nothing to do with Postfix's settings. Since you haven't set such a shell/environment variable in anything the shell has read, it will result in an empty string (blank).

To view the `myorigin` setting of Postfix, you should run `sudo postconf myorigin` instead.

The Postfix setting `myorigin = /etc/mailname` tells Postfix to read the actual `myorigin` value from a file named `/etc/mailname`. So if what you want to get is the actual hostname Postfix is going to use as a source address on outgoing emails, you can simply run `cat /etc/mailname` instead.